# Lead Lag Correlations for individual years of 2 arrays of same size in Python

Tags: python, scipy, correlation, cross-correlation, scipy.stats

I have two arrays of the same size
x (1900) and y (1900), both are daily data starting from August to Oct for every year.
I want to calculate the cross-correlation between these 2 arrays for each year separately and store it in a separate array.

Method 1:

```
# cross correlation using xcorr()
# function
ax1.xcorr(x, y, usevlines=True,
          maxlags=50, normed=True,
          lw=2)
```

Method 2:

```
correlation = signal.correlate(x, y, mode="full")
lags = signal.correlation_lags(x.size, y.size, mode="full")
lag = lags[np.argmax(correlation)]
```

Both options consider x and y as continuous arrays.
Whereas, I want to calculate based on time, for each year separately.